# Nvidia Driver on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: ubuntu, driver, nvidia

Is there any avaliable nvidia driver for Geforce RTX 2070Super on Ubuntu 20.04.i checked, but i couldnt find. I code
`nvidia-smi`. There is no response

Comment: wrong place to ask about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this live iso_image fully functioning with latest nvidia drivers

https://sourceforge.net/projects/toysbox/files/bionic-nvidia/ubuntu-20.04-5.4.0-26-generic-nvidia-450.57-primeselect.iso

and if you want to install you can !!!

But to fully have prime-select acting on switch off nvidia gpu when you switch to intel card you need to include on kernel cmdline at boot with pcie_port_port=off once you installed
Don't forget to change /etc/default/grub the line

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

into

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_port_pm=off"`

to allow future grub-update

otherwise the nvidia gpu card remains on when switching back
and forth between intel and nvidia but of course it's working .

hoan